# Trivial Grothendieck topology and identity morphisms

Tags: grothendieck-topology

So on nLab the definition of a trivial (Grothendieck) topology is the following: "The Grothendieck topology on any category for which only the identity morphisms are covering is the trivial topology. Its sheaves are all the presheaves."

I am having trouble understanding what is meant exactly by only the "identity morphisms are covering." After reading a bit, I was under the impression that those are of the form $\hom(-,X)$, but then I don't understand what the link is with what I traditionally understand as "identity morphisms", which to me are of the form $1_X$ for objects $X\in\operatorname{Obj}(C)$. Am I missing something obvious or is the definition of identity morphisms different in this context?

Comment: Fair enough but then I'm not sure why they have this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+pretopology
Is this a different notion of (Grothendieck) pretopology?

Comment: Clearly there is a smallest topology on $\mathcal C$, and for this topology every presheaf is a sheaf. This is called the trivial topology. It is the topology for which the only covering sieve of an object $X$ is the maximal sieve on $X$. I don't know what the writer meant by "only the identity morphisms are coverings". Maybe by "the morphism $f:Y\to X$ is a covering" they mean that ${f}$ is a covering family. But in the trivial topology that is true not only for every identity morphism but also for every morphism that has a left inverse (and only for these).

Comment: What do you mean by "those" in "those are of the form $hom(-,X)$?

Comment: Thanks for your response. By "those" I meant the so-called "identity morphisms", thinking that it was maybe another way of calling those hom sets I hadn't seen before. This is why I was very confused at the notation there. "The smallest topology on C" makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, a Grothendieck topology is specified by its covering sieves, not its covers, so it would have been more accurate to say the covering sieves of the trivial topology are those generated by identity morphisms.  The cover of $X$ by the sieve $hom(-,X)$ is indeed the sieve generated by the identity morphism of $X$.  Taken literally, most categories do not admit a Grothendieck topology in which the *only* covers are identity maps, since whenever an identity morphism is a cover so is every isomorphism with the same target.

Comment: And so is every split epimorphism with the same target.